# Two entities with 2 join table in doctrine 2

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, database-schema

I am working on courts projects. where 2 parties are involved. One party who filed the case against second party. each party may have more than 1 advocate for represent his case. and one advocate has more than 1 case. This situation is the many to many relationship. i designed this structure, this is the rough example.

[image]

How can i define such relationship in doctrine 2. I tried this

Advocate:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CaseLaw\CaseLaw\Entity\CaseLaw", mappedBy="caseLawFirstPartyAdvocates")
 **/
private $caseLaw;
```

CaseLaw

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="CaseLaw\Advocates\Entity\Advocates", inversedBy="caseLaw")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="case_law_first_party_advocates", 
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="case_law_id", referencedColumnName="case_law_id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="advocate_id", referencedColumnName="advocate_id")})
 **/


private $caseLawFirstPartyAdvocates;

   /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "Advocates", inversedBy="caseLaw")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="case_law_first_party_advocates", 
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="case_law_id", referencedColumnName="case_law_id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="advocate_id", referencedColumnName="advocate_id")})
     **/
   private $caseLawSecondPartyAdovcates;
```

**The Problem is, Value of MappedBy attribute is caseLawFirstPartyAdvocates, where i can specify second attribute caseLawsecondPartyAdvocates ?. how can i define annotation of this kink of situation ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a direct answer to your question, but I'm going to recommend that you try http://www.orm-designer.com to help you figure it out. It's not free, but the developer is very active with updates, and us very responsive to suggestions and to support questions.

Comment: I download this software, and create my scenario and export the annotations and figure out that how they solve this problem. Thanks, this software is very easy and helpful.